# Must I reset the webclient?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I've made my own highscore "service" in php/mysql to go with my C#/XNA/WP7 game.

At first look it looks great, but it does not update without closing the application and starting it.

What I'm doing:

- Start game, look at highscore, play game, enter score, look at highscore
  in this scenario I see no changes in the highscore but if I restart the game I do. If I play the game directly without looking at the highscore I will see the fresh highscore :(

I put a breakpoint at the data I got back from the server and it has returned the same thing. But if I restart the game I get the fresh highscore list.

Does anyone know whats broken?

Comment: Can you show the class your using to call your web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a caching issue. Check your response object to see if the IsFromCache property is true. If it is, there are a few different ways to deal with it.

Add cache control headers on the server side as described in Example #2 of the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) article on the PHP site:

> Example #2 Caching directives
>
> PHP scripts often generate dynamic content that must not be cached by
>   the client browser or any proxy caches between the server and the
>   client browser. Many proxies and clients can be forced to disable
>   caching with:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

> Note:
>
> You may find that your pages aren't cached even if you don't output
>   all of the headers above. There are a number of options that users may
>   be able to set for their browser that change its default caching
>   behavior. By sending the headers above, you should override any
>   settings that may otherwise cause the output of your script to be
>   cached.
>
> Additionally, session_cache_limiter() and the session.cache_limiter
>   configuration setting can be used to automatically generate the
>   correct caching-related headers when sessions are being used.

Change the caching policy for your application domain on the client:

```
// Set a default policy level for the "http:" and "https" schemes.
HttpRequestCachePolicy policy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Default);
HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = policy;
```

Change the caching policy for the web request on the client:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
// Define a cache policy for this request only. 
HttpRequestCachePolicy noCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
request.CachePolicy = noCachePolicy;
```

See the MSDN documentation for [HttpRequestCacheLevel Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cache.httprequestcachelevel.aspx) for more information on the client side methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's your problem, but I have encountered annoying cache issues with the webclient. Basically, the request is cached the first time, then the next times I get the same content even if the page was updated. I found no way to clear the cache, so I solved the problem by adding a random parameter at the end of the uri. For instance:

`http://www.example.com/yourPage.html?nocache=45646487`

This way, you are sure that you never send the same request twice.